# ReactJS: Array became [object object] in between methods

Tags: reactjs, antd

i am using the antd editableCell example https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell

For some reason when the handleSave callback is executed, the record object passed became [object object].

Any idea why? There isn't really anything changed from the example code really.

In the EditableCell component

```
const EditableCell = ({
  title,
  editable,
  children,
  dataIndex,
  record,
  handleSave,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const form = useContext(EditableContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [editing]);

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    console.log("toggle edit tapped ", record);
    setEditing(!editing);    
    form.setFieldsValue({
      [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex],
    });
  };

  const save = async () => {
    try {
      const values = await form.validateFields();
      toggleEdit();
      console.log("record to be saved", record, values);
    
      handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
    }
  };
```

In the main class

```
 const columns = defaultColumns.map((col) => {
        if (!col.editable) {
          return col;
        }
    
        return {
          ...col,
          onCell: (record) => ({
            record,
            editable: col.editable,
            dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
            title: col.title,
            handleSave,
          }),
        };
      }); 
        
     const handleSave = async (row) => {
            const newData = [...dataSource];
            console.log("final save to send ", row)
            let result = await triggerSaveToServer(row);
            console.log("result saved ", result)
return (
    <div>
    <Space direction="vertical">
    <Search
      placeholder="Key in environment code"
      onSearch={onSearch}
      style={{
        width: 200,
      }}
  />

<Table
         size="small"
        columns={columns}
        components={components}
        rowkey={(record) => record._id}
        expandable={{
          expandedRowRender,
          defaultExpandedRowKeys: ['0'],
        }}
        dataSource={dataSource}
      />
   
     </Space>
    </div>
  );
```

error which shows the two console statements, the caller is a proper object, the receiver gets it as [Object Object]

[image]

Comment: I think your question doesn't have enough of your code for us to help you debug the problem. If you haven't already, I suggest installing the React Dev Tools. You can use these to inspect component state and props. Hopefully that will help you trace the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Try logging, JSON.stringiy(object), and then compare.

Comment: Thanks i have installed reactdev but dosen't really tell me anything. Because the data is picked up as an array. But somehow during the callback (handleSave) it becomes [object Object]. Its really strange.

Comment: The source code is actually a copy paste of the example javascript code from here. The main difference is that i have a nested array in the data https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell